# How is web.whatsapp.com supposed to work on an Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: webapps, whatsapp

If I open [WhatsApp Web](https://web.whatsapp.com/) in Chrome I get a blank window with this in the middle:

[image]

Nothing happens and nothing is clickable.
Shouldn't it be displaying a QR code to scan from my phone?

**What's supposed to happen next?**

```
Chrome: Version 109.0.5414.119 (Official Build) (64-bit))
    All extensions disabled.
Ubuntu 20.4, fully updated: `uname -a` = 
    Linux ray-desktop 5.15.0-46-generic #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP
    Thu Aug 4 19:15:44 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The Chrome console shows:

[image]

Comment: It works for me in all browsers.

Comment: Same problem here in Chrome under 22.10. I switched to MS Edge. It works there with no problem...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Google Chrome *does* have some problems with [WhatsApp Web](https://web.whatsapp.com/).

Before trying anything else, you should open an *Incognito Window* in  Chrome and try there. If it works there, it is probably due to cache, cookies, and other site data saved for this web site: Try to clear them and retry.

However, I my case, the problem seems to be related *somehow* with the extensions I use on Chrome.

Please, go to Chrome's **Settings** → **Extensions**, disable the extensions one by one, and try to open the web site. For example, in my case it seems that the extension named "**Set Character Encoding**" was the culprit.

The strange thing is that, once the extension is disabled and the web site starts working, you can re-enable the extension and still use the web site... **Until the problem re-occurs.**

So, after a while I decided to use another dedicated browser, like Microsoft Edge just for [WhatsApp Web](https://web.whatsapp.com/). It works with no problem so far.

Comment: The Incognito worked.  Then in the normal window I disabled *all* extensions and it still failed as described. So I cleared all the local and session data for the site and reloaded. It did put up the login information box this time, but at the top in red was "*A database error occurred on your browser. Please relink your device.*". Reloading went back to the mostly empty screen.  At least I know now that it isn't something that *I'm* doing wrong.  Thanks.